# Is it possible to capture the iOS GPU frame time using XCode or XCode Instruments?

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, opengl-es, unity-game-engine

I am trying to write an automated profiling tool which will use XCode Instruments to load and run an iOS game, and gather profile and timing information about the rendered scene in the game. Specifically I want to know how many milliseconds the scene takes to render on the GPU. From what I can gather about Instruments, I can call it in such a way as it will output profile data to a file, for later examination.

I know that the GPU frametime can be viewed if I run the game from XCode and I can see that on the Performance panel of XCode the frame time of both GPU and CPU is displayed. But I cannot find anyway of accessing this information so that I can write it out to a file for examination later.

Is it possible to capture the iOS GPU frame time using XCode or XCode Instruments?

I am currently using XCode Version 4.6.1, and running a Unity 4 app ( the built in iOS GPU profiler for Unity is wildly inaccurate and useless for my needs ).

Thanks
George

Comment: I should add that I have tried using XCode OpenGL ES Driver Instrument and OpenGL ES Analysis Instrument, and neither of these provide a GPU frame time (or equivalent) statistic